# Community ads listed as low quality answers

Tags: feature-request, review, advertising

Shouldn't [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) answers be excluded from the review page, or at least calculated differently? The automatically generated quality indicter seems to be based on the contents and length of answers, this doesn't exactly apply to Community Ads which have more or less the same contents (an image with a link).

Comment: Doesn't this only apply to Meta SO?

Comment: @Chris: Other sites also have community ads, I don't know if they too appear in the 'low quality posts' report.

Comment: Since community-ads is a moderator only tag it seems reasonable  (you wouldn't want it on a normal tag). But it only [represents 6 posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all&tag=community-ads) so IMHO it doesn't seem to be a burning issue.

Comment: @ConradFrix: This isn't an urgent feature request but SE seems to take pride in the little details.